# Difference between 尽管 and 虽然

Tags: grammar

In this sentence should I use both 尽管/虽然 or not?

I really like doing sports. Although I have many lessons every day, after four o'clock I'll be in the gym running and swimming. My friend Maria even likes to practice taijiquan with the master.

我很多喜欢运动。尽管/虽然我每天都有很多上课，但是下午四点以后去体育馆跑步，游泳。连我朋友玛丽也喜欢跟老师打太极拳。

The hotter it is, the better I feel. But even though it's very hot these days, I think I got a flu and my head hurts more and more.
天侯越热身体越好
尽管/虽然 这些天很热但是我感冒了头越来越疼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"尽管" means more like "even if". "虽然" means "although".

Ironically, your sentence has major mistakes elsewhere:

> (Yours) 我很多喜欢运动。{尽管/虽然}我每天都有很多上课，但是下午四点以后去体育馆跑步，游泳。连我朋友玛丽也喜欢跟老师打太极拳。

"很多" is an adjective, so it cannot modify verbs like "喜欢" or "上课".

> (Fixed) 我真喜欢运动。{尽管/虽然}我每天都有很多课，但是下午四点后还会去体育馆跑步，游泳。我的朋友玛丽也喜欢跟老师练太极拳。

I do not agree with *jack chiou* that the difference between "尽管" and "虽然" is strength of emotion. The difference is almost precisely the difference between "even if" and "although".

For example, "虽然" / "although" cannot be used with a counter-factual condition (at least formally).

> (Right) 尽管我们有翅膀，还是飞不到太阳。 = Even if we have wings, we still cannot fly to the sun.
>
> (Wrong) 虽然我们有翅膀，但是飞不到太阳。 = Although we have wings, we cannot fly to the sun.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically ,尽管 and 虽然 two words are no essential difference.

Both 尽管 and 虽然 are right to place in XX.

> 我真的很喜欢运动。 XX我每天都有很多的课，但四点以后，我還是會在体育馆跑步和游泳。 我的朋友玛丽亚甚至喜欢跟大师练习太极拳。
>
> 天气越热，我感觉更好。 但是，XX这几天天气很热，我还是觉得自己得了流感，而且头部越来越痛。

The emotion of 尽管 is stronger than 虽然.So it is often to see us use 虽然.

Answer (score 2):

儘管 have broader meaning than 雖然.

According to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education in Taiwan.

[雖然](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000145759) means:

> 縱然、即使。

(Even if)

[儘管](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000094551) means:

不加限制，隨意去做。

(Do somethings without limit)

即使、雖然。

(Even if)

Answer (score 1):

Use 虽然 or 尽管??

I really like doing sports.
我很喜欢运动。

Although I have many lessons every day, (and you'd think I might be tired)
虽然/尽管我每天都有许多节课 （either will do)

after four o'clock I'll be in the gym running and swimming.
我仍然会在四点以后去体育馆跑步和游泳。（我仍然会 = I still will)

My friend Maria even likes to practice taijiquan with the master.  (even = also)
我的朋友，玛丽亚还喜欢和教练一起练习太极拳。

The hotter it is, the better I feel.
天气越热，我感觉越好。

Even though it's very hot these days,
尽管这些天非常炎热，(use 尽管)

I think I got a flu and my head hurts more and more.
我还是觉得我得了流感，我的头越来越疼。